# Find a set of matching words with MySQL

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a string for example:

`MatchString = "Renal and Dialysis Technologist and Technician"`

I have a table that has a field called `degree_name`

As an example one of the degree names may be `Dialysis Technician`.

I want to try to find degrees that contain a number of the words from the `MatchString` above - maybe like 2 or 3 matches - is there an easy way to do this in mysql - if so what would the code look like?

Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing about it, but when it comes to matching non-exact results, I've always assumed that [Sphinx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_%28search_engine%29) was the way to go. But I could be way off...

Comment: Using MySQL's [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html), you could do something like `WHERE MATCH(degree_name) AGAINST 'Renal and Dialysis Technologist and Technician'`.

Comment: sorry for the confusion - when i mean 2 or 3 matches i mean 2 or 3 words match the original MatchString - not 2 or 3 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be getting good results with a full text search in boolean mode. First make sure your table is MyISAM, with a full text index on `degree_name`. Then this query will return matches, and number of words matching your `MatchString`:

```
SELECT degree_name,
MATCH (degree_name)
AGAINST ('Renal and Dialysis Technologist and Technician' IN BOOLEAN MODE) FROM degrees
WHERE MATCH (degree_name)
AGAINST ('Renal and Dialysis Technologist and Technician' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use, WHERE LIKE 'Dialysis Technician%'  that will give you a two word match.  If you want three you would need to add additional words in the like.  The % is looking for wildcards after the text so if you would like to see info from before Dialysis Technician if would need to look like this: WHERE LIKE '%Dialysis Technician'.